# Access relationship from WhereIn

Tags: php, laravel

My query is:

```
$posts = Post::
    whereIn('ID', (
    NewsTag::
             orderBy('post_date','desc')->with('publisher','newsTopics')
                 ->paginate(12)->pluck('post_id')))
             ->get();
```

Newstag.php model is like this:

```
            public function newsTopics() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\NewsTopics', 'post_id', 'post_id');
    }

    public function publisher() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Publisher', 'id', 'publisher_id');
    }
```

I'm not being able to get access to publisher and newsTopics when I do something like:

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
//doesn't work this way
$post->publisher->name;

//nor like this
$publisher->name;
```

How can I get access to publisher and newsTopics? When I run this controller, it does query what I want but I just don't have access over it.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: The `with` & `paginate` inside your `whereIn` does nothing to the result of the query, i suggest you remove it and put it outside of the `WhereIn`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in order to get the model relation you have to load them first in your query:

```
$posts = Post::with('newsTopics','publisher')->
    whereIn('ID', (
    NewsTag::
             orderBy('post_date','desc')->with('publisher','newsTopics')
                 ->paginate(12)->pluck('post_id')))
             ->get();
```

then you can access your relation like:

```
@foreach($posts as $post)

$publisherName= $post->publisher->name;
```

more details in:

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading